# Is it possible to convert xml telemetry to json in Thingsboard

Tags: xml, rest, thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

My target api returns xml structured telemetry data. How can I convert it to json within Thingsboard CE, preferably using TBEL?
Could I alternatively use a converter within Thingsboard-gateway?

Debugging the rest response in the rulechain shows a successful response containing structured xml data

Comment: Did you find the solution? I'm in exactly the same situation.

Comment: I'm still working through it as I have time . The approach I've taken is using the tb-gateway with a custom request connector. The custom uplink converter does the xml to json conversion. Next is working through passing url parameters from tb to tb-gateway

Comment: Please elaborate more about the custom request connector and how you managed to pass URL parameters from tb to the tb-gateway.